# Is there an event just before the radio button is about the be checked

Tags: jquery

This is the part of the code for one of the radio buttons:

```
$("#new").click(function(){
    if( $('#new').is(':checked') )
        $.jGrowl("You already have this option selected!", life: 1500});
    else
        changeOption(1);
});
```

Now, I understand that the `else` part will never run, because the radio button will be already checked on click event. What I'm wondering is, is there an event which would let me capture the state of the radio button (which is about to be clicked) and therefor determine if he is not yet clicked, and if so change the option to this newly selected one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the mouseup event instead.

```
$("#new").mouseup(function(){
    if( $('#new').is(':checked') )
        $.jGrowl("You already have this option selected!", life: 1500});
    else
        changeOption(1);
});
```

The [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/SCF5K/)

**Edit**
Even though the mouseup event works, it seems more logical to use the mousedown event. [Here's that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/SCF5K/3/).

Answer (score 6):

Store the initial value in a data attribute, and use that on changes:

```
$.each($("input[type='radio']"), function(i,e) {
    $(e).data('check', e.checked);
});

$("#new").on('click keyup', function(){
    if( $(this).data('check') ) {
        alert("You already have this option selected!");
    }else{
        alert("This option is unselected");
    }
    $(this).data('check', this.checked);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SCF5K/2/)

Even works with keyboard events.

Comment: ah, if nothing, for the humor attempt +1 ;)

Comment: The third code block is in actuality a good solution (I started reading this answer, got my hopes up about the mindReader event for a instant, laughed, then moved to the next question not realizing it was a serious answer).

Answer (score 2):

The mousedown event should work. It triggers when the element is clicked, before the mouse button is released.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: yes, you're right, why don't you post an answer so I can accept? user1546010: it's mouseup event that works for me, not mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just uncheck it, if it may not be checked?

```
$("#new").click(function(){
    if( $('#new').is(':checked') ){
        $.jGrowl("You already have this option selected!", life: 1500});
        $('#new').attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        changeOption(1);
        $('#new').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```